# Get first element using Zend_Dom_Query

Tags: zend-framework, zend-dom-query

I want to get the first element using Zend_Dom_Query
Example I have 2 forms in document:

```
<html><form/><form/></html>
```

How can I get the first form? I tried this: `$dom->query('form:eq(1)')` like jQuery selector but not success. Can you help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Zend_Dom_Query has a somewhat limited but pretty decent set of supported CSS selectors. `:eq`, though, is a jQuery-specific extension, not an actual CSS selector.

You could use Zend_Dom_Query's XPath support instead, something like:

```
$dom->queryXpath('//form[1]');
```